# Terminology Questions: Data-structure consisting of lists without repetitions

Tags: data-structures, reference-request, category-theory, linked-lists, lists

I've google around and have been unsuccessful in finding a name for a data-structure consisting of a list whose elements are unique.

I've seen "unique *sorted* lists", but I'm looking into the more general, not necessarily sorted, case.

Does anyone know a name and a source for such things? --e.g., a one word name for them.

Moreover, lists may be construed as initial algebras or the solutions to a family of recursive equations involving constructors, say, `nil` and `cons`. What possible equational algebra gives rise to lists without repetitions? That is, do they pop-out as a solution to some family or are they an algebraic data type that has certain equational constraints, if so which ones?

Comment: This is similar to an *ordered dictionary*. You might call it an *ordered set*.

Comment: As mentioned above, I'm specifically avoiding the particular case of things being ordered.

Comment: In that case, you're interested in the *set* data structure.

Comment: An order statistic tree is a tree that supports efficient select and rank queries (log n) which means it is an effcient list implementation. It is implemented on top a of a bst set data structure.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus No, I want it to be a *listing*, whence ordering matters. In a *set*, order is irrelevant.

Comment: In that case, you're interested in an ordered set. We can continue this back and forth for a few more rounds, but the end result would be either an ordered set or a (regular) set.

Comment: It seems I'm not communicating as clearly as I thought. Please let me try yet again. I am interested in a list, that is to say an ordered collection where multiplicity matters and so different from a set where not only multiplicity but also ordering is irrelevant. Moreover I would like such a list to have unique elements. For example, `[1, 3,2]` and `[2, 1, 3` are **distinct** such lists ---but as sets they are the *same*, which is not desired.

Comment: As @YuvalFilmus said, that would be an 'ordered set', meaning that having a different order is a way to distingsuish sets that are otherwise the same.

Comment: You asked for the name of this data structure. Well, it's called an *ordered set*, see for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653970/does-python-have-an-ordered-set). The name might confuse you – an ordered set *isn't* a set. It's a data structure which has some similarities to the set data structure, but also some differences.